# Correct way to get info from models in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to get list of emails of people, who had chosen value1. This is my code:

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            option = request.POST.getlist('my_field')
            new_user = form.save(email, option)
            list = Vartotojas.objects.filter(option=u"Value1").values_list("email", flat=True) 
# Here I am trying to get list of emails, who chose Value 1
```

forms.py

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('Value1','Value1'),('Value2','Value2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def save(self, email, option):
        mymodel = Vartotojas(
        email=email,
        option = option,
        )
        mymodel.save()
```

models.py

```
option = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

However, insted of list of emails I get empty list. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could you show `Vartotojas` model?

Comment: I found mistake.You was right, it's in the model.py. Thanks :)